# Specifying distance

Tags: grammaticality

Regarding description of relative position which one is right:

1. the antenna is installed in 20cm distance from the beam center.
2. the antenna is installed at 20cm from the beam center.

Comment: You don't need any preposition before a distance measurement, so you could write 'the antenna is installed 20cm from the beam center', but if you want one, use 'at'.

Comment: If it's supposed to be *exactly* 20cm away from the beam centre, what @MichaelHarvey says is correct (no preposition is required, so it would not normally be used). But often you might write something like *Install the antenna **within** 20cm from the beam center* to mean ***no further than 20cm away*** (but it could optionally be ***closer***, at the installer's discretion). Personally, I'd change the other preposition to *...within 20cm **of** the beam center* for that exact construction, but ***from*** is at least "acceptable".

Comment: Here's some re-usable advice: to install X at a distance of Y from Z.

Answer (score 1):

No preposition is best.

> the antenna is installed 20cm from the beam center.

Comment: As a matter of typography, the numerical value always precedes the unit and a space is always used to separate the unit from the number, according to the International System of Units (PDF) (9th ed.).  Thus 2 cm rather than 2cm.  International Bureau of Weights and Measures. 2019. p. 150. ISBN 978-92-822-2272-0.  Retrieved 2019-11-13.

[https://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si-brochure/SI-Brochure-9.pdf]